# Regex match skipping first match

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, logging, match

So I have a certain log file:

```
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/admin] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@75443fb0]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.jaxb.MultiValueMapAdapter=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@53b177f5, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.PrincipleImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@283aa0c0, class java.util.ArrayList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@210fb1e2, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.jaxb.MultivalueMapEntry=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@d677d63, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.context.builders.SecurityContextSectionBuilder$SecurityContextSectionImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@558f575, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.authz.internal.AuthzPermissionImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@135ad711, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.context.builders.GroupBuilder$GroupImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@30dda704, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.context.builders.RoleBuilder$RoleImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@280010ac, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.jaxb.MultivalueMap=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@1c46a0b8, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.SecurityContextImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@60e19e88}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:08 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/admin] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1@7c6f2468]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@64bf67aa]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:09 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/admin] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@75443fb0]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.PrincipleImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@522efd92, class java.util.ArrayList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@b09a665, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.jaxb.MultivalueMapEntry=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@268b368c, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.context.builders.SecurityContextSectionBuilder$SecurityContextSectionImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@7daa3518, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.authz.internal.AuthzPermissionImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@3183fb1c, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.context.builders.GroupBuilder$GroupImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@4fdb04a9, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.context.builders.RoleBuilder$RoleImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@340f1c34, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.jaxb.MultivalueMap=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@4c04b49f, class com.hp.sw.bto.security.internal.SecurityContextImpl=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@48ee59b6}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/admin] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1@7c6f2468]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1843e122]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

And I am trying to parse it. However, when I try my regex on a test, it works fine and matches what I want. http://regex101.com/r/sL4eR0/13
But when I try it out on code, it skips the first match and output all matches afterwards. I am not too sure why or how to fix it. 
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/j7rXu/6/

Comment: FYI, the regex101 patter is lacking the ^ at the beginning, but, when the ^ is placed, it does work, so your question stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the call to `regex.test(localcat)` is eating the first match of the regex. If you remove this line prior to the loop calling `regex.exec(localcat)` it should include the first match in the loop.

```
var match, regex = /^([a-zA-Z]*): (.*)(?:\s)([^co]+) ([^\s]+) (\w*)$/gm, localcat = ((reader.result).split("\n").reverse().join("\n"));

// This line eats the first match of the regex
// alert(regex.test(localcat)); 

while ((match = regex.exec(localcat)) !== null){    
    alert(match[0]);

    if(match[1]==="SEVERE"){        
        document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML+= ("Time: " + match[3] + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

The [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for RegExp.prototype.test() states:

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times
>   on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the
>   previous match.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea why it does this? @Daws

Comment: Your explanation is very strange and can't be true since the missing record is the fourth in the file.

Comment: @user3780650, I believe regex.test() method is designed to work in combination with the exec() method, although I'm not completely sure why! See the description at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test.

Comment: @Daws: I can't believe it! I have tested it and indeed I obtain the behaviour you described when you mix the `test` and the `exec` method. Incredible! However even with this fix there is always one missing record (instead of two). I believe that the reason is in my answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Excellent point, I didn't even notice at first that the last entry was missed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your pattern no more works is that your split/reverse/join all the lines before applying the pattern. Consequence, all the dates that are on separate lines are now before each record, but your pattern is designed to work with the original order. See how `localcat` looks like after the split/reverse/join:

```
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader check...
SEVERE: The web application [/admin] created a ThreadLocal with key of type...
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:08 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader check...
SEVERE: The web application [/admin] created a ThreadLocal with key of type...
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:09 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader check...
SEVERE: The web application [/admin] created a ThreadLocal with key of type...
Jul 07, 2014 12:56:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader check...
SEVERE: The web application [/admin] created a ThreadLocal with key of type...
```

This is why you obtain all the records except the last with the date/time of previous record.

The good way is probably to extract all the data you want and only after to reverse the result array. An other possibility is to rewrite your pattern for this new order ([see demo](http://regex101.com/r/gT7fE5/1)). You can choose to work line by line too.